# How do I find the account a steam game belongs to?

Tags: steam

I own a hard copy of Left 4 Dead but unfortunately it is registered to my old Steam account, which I made several years ago and have since forgotten the password and even the username. Is there a way to enter the CD key and find the account it is attached to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way would be through the [email address associated](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4988-DHXV-7272) with the account. A reverse-engineering from the CD key to any account name is not possible.

Comment: Yeah it seemed like a long shot. Just thought there might have been some more insight to find

Answer (score 3):

[uncovery](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/38175/uncovery)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107324/53249) is not actually true: there's a legit way to discover, which account your CD-Key belongs to by contacting [Steam Support](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpRequestCantLogin/?issueid=406).

You need to mention that you have forgotten your account name and the only proof you have is the CD-Key. Be honest with them and they'll definitely help you.